How to tell VB.net that a base class method implements an interface method
In c# I can write the following piece of code:
public class SomeClass
{
    public interface IMyInterface
    {
        DialogResult ShowDialog();
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form, SomeClass.IMyInterface 
{
}

This works because c# automatically "maps" the ShowDialog() method of the interface to the method with the same name implemented in Form.
In VB I have to explicitly declare that a method in the class implements an interface method:
Public Function ShowDialog() As DialogResult Implements SomeClass.ShowDialog
    '...
End Function

But this way I'm redefining an already defined method.
Of course I can create a helper function:
Public Function IMyInterface_ShowDialog() As DialogResult Implements SomeClass.ShowDialog
    Return ShowDialog()
End Function

but I wonder if this is the best practice in this case, or if I can somehow refer to the already implemented method.

that is basically the same, only in c# much is done in the background

You're right! I tried to open a c# test executable with dnSpy and found out that it contains a helper function that returns base.ShowDialog(). Thank you!

For this case, you might want to consider making the auxiliary implementation routine Private since you probably don't intend for a client to call it directly (vs through the interface).
